# How to get automatically different images using modal in Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use modals with cards in Semantic UI. The concept is to click on the button on the card and display a modal with an image and description. I have 48 cards and I need different images with an every click on the card --> When I click on the card nr 1 - it shows the image number1, when I click on the card number2- it shows the image number 2, when I click on the card number 48- it shows the image nr 48 etc.
How can I get automatically each image from the card?

I'm a quite beginner with this stuff and I'm wondering if there is possible to use .append() with .each() in that case? Like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('.ui.modal > .image').append($('.dimage')); //it adds only one image, but maybe there's a way to adds other ones using this script                                                                                                          with minor modifications        
});
</script>
```

This is excerpt from my code:

```
<!--head-->
<script>
$(function(){
   $('.center > .ui.inverted.button').click(function(){
      $('.ui.modal').modal('show');         
   });
});
</script>

<!-- my body-->    
<div class="ui basic container">
   <div class="ui four doubling special cards">

      <div class="card">
         <div class="blurring dimmable image">
            <div class="ui dimmer">
               <div class="content">
                  <div class="center">
                     <div class="ui inverted button">Show</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div><!--ui dimmer-->
            <img src="images/snacks/snack9.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <a class="header">Snacks</a>
            <div class="meta">
               <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div><!--card-->

      <div class="card">
         <div class="blurring dimmable image">
            <div class="ui dimmer">
               <div class="content">
                  <div class="center">
                     <div class="ui inverted button">Show</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div><!--ui dimmer-->
            <img src="images/snacks/snack10.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <a class="header">Snacks</a>
            <div class="meta">
               <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div><!--card-->

      <div class="card">
         <div class="blurring dimmable image">
            <div class="ui dimmer">
               <div class="content">
                  <div class="center">
                     <div class="ui inverted button">Show</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div><!--ui dimmer-->
            <img src="images/snacks/snack11.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <a class="header">Snacks</a>
            <div class="meta">
               <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div><!--card-->

      <div class="card">
         <div class="blurring dimmable image">
            <div class="ui dimmer">
               <div class="content">
                  <div class="center">
                     <div class="ui inverted button">Show</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div><!--ui dimmer-->
            <img class="dimage" src="images/snacks/snack12.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <a class="header">Snacks</a>
            <div class="meta">
               <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div><!--card-->

   </div><!--ui four doubling special cards-->
       <div class="ui modal">
          <i class="close icon"></i>
          <div class="header">
             Modal Title
          </div>
          <div class="image content">
             <div class="image">
             An image can appear on the left
             </div>
             <div class="description">
                A description can appear on the right
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div><!--ui basic container-->
```

Comment: So you click on the button in the card. This launches the reusable modal with a description/image related to that card, correct? Where is the description and image coming from?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Descriptions will be inside divs with the class "meta" (the text on the card) or something similar. Images can be also in meta or html data field - card will use smaller version of the image "snack12.jpg" but modal will use large version "snack12_large.jpg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below: https://jsfiddle.net/y7nd7qxw/. I had to adjust your card HTML a bit because the button wasn't showing up, but with the CSS you probably have it should be fine how you had it. Basically what I'm doing is storing the modal information on the `data-` attributes of your button. Then I'm getting those values in the click event and assigning them to the elements in the modal.

```
<!--head-->
<script>
$(function() {

    var modal = $('#my-modal'), // hold reference to modal
        modalImg = $('#modal-img'), // hold reference to image in modal
        modalDesc = $('#modal-desc'); // hold reference to description in modal

    //give your button an easier class reference
    $('.show-modal').on('click', function() {
        var button = $(this);

        modalImg.attr('src', button.data('img'));
        modalDesc.text(button.data('desc'));

        modal.modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
<!-- my body-->
<div class="ui basic container">
    <div class="ui four doubling special cards">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="blurring dimmable image">
                <div class="ui inverted button show-modal" data-desc="here is some description" data-img="http://placehold.it/200">Show</div>
                <!--ui dimmer-->
                <img src="images/snacks/snack9.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a class="header">Snacks</a>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--card-->

        <div class="card">
            <div class="blurring dimmable image">
                <div class="ui inverted button show-modal" data-desc="some other description description" data-img="http://placehold.it/400">Show</div>
                <!--ui dimmer-->
                <img src="images/snacks/snack9.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a class="header">Snacks</a>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span class="date">veggie/fruity</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--card-->
    </div>
    <!--ui four doubling special cards-->
    <div class="ui modal" id="my-modal">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        <div class="header">
            Modal Title
        </div>
        <div class="image content">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="" alt="" id="modal-img">
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p id="modal-desc"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--ui basic container-->
```